# media query is not working on actual mobile devices but working on browser inspect

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I'm having this problem lately, When I'm using a media query on my CSS the media is working fine on inspecting elements on the browser the style of the media query I've set is working when viewing it on the browser inspect element. However, when I'm checking it on actual mobile devices it's not working can anyone help me why it's not working on a mobile device? Does my viewport is correct? Please see the viewport below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0,
    initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Comment: I'm using this viewport. Is this correct? 


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes"/>

Comment: Can anyone help me if my viewport meta is the one causing problem

Comment: Can you post the media query that isnt working? It could be unrelated to your viewport meta

Comment: Have you got everything set up that might be needed in the code (like a body element e.g.?)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:
This is what most developers use except on rare occasions.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```